# jQuery Accordion

Tags: jquery

My Accordion menu HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="http://google.com">Accordion Header</a>
      <ul>
       <li>
         <a href="http://another.com">Link 1</a>       
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="http://another.com">Link 2</a>      
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="http://another.com">Link 3</a>      
       </li>
      <ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Currently there is a click event when clicking the `<li>` wrapping the first `<a...>Accordion Header</a>` which expands the menu items below.

However when clicking the link: `<a href="http://google.com">Accordion Header</a>` the link gets loaded and the accordion expands.

Is there anyway, using jQuery, to prevent the click on the `<a>` from expanding the Accordion? Is there some kind of function I can use, `.stop`?

Comment: Can I ask why you are using an accordion if you don't want the headers to expand/contract upon clicking them?

Comment: I do want the Headers to expand, but not when the link in the header is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `e.preventDefault()` which will stop it.  Also returning false should work.